# about stability of selection sort in an example, is this correct?

Tags: sorting

I have seen an example about the stability of selection and insertion sort applied to a set of internet transactions:

[image]

And I have made one pass to try to sort it by using selection sort using the location criteria:

[image]

I mean for what I know the selection sort chooses the index of the element in the unordered part, right section, and puts it into the front of the left section. In the first pass Chicago 09:00:00 is in the right position, there is no other Chicago with less time. Then we pass to Phoenix 09:00:03, so we check up for a smaller element in the right part (which is Chicago 09:00:59), because this element is smaller we should end up with:

```
Chicago 09:00:00
Chicago 09:00:59
```

but in the example says that because we used selection sort is unstable, and that with insertion sort it can be stable

what am I doing wrong in my comparisons?

Also I saw another example here that puts this example:

```
Sort this elements
(4,0)(4,1)(1,0)
```

Alright if I use selection sort and I only check it up the first element of each tuple I will end up with:

```
(1,0)(4,1)(4,0)
```

ok it seems it is not stable, but it says that if we use insertion sort we will end up with:

```
(1,0)(4,0)(4,1)
```

but if I make a slight change to the original array to:

```
(4,1)(4,0)(1,0)
```

and we compare only the first element, insertion sort will also not be stable because we will end up with:

```
(1,0)(4,1)(4,0)
```

ok, if we took both elements to be compared then the selection sort can also be stable
what is wrong with these proofs?

Comment: This question is better suited to http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

In your last example, the insertion sort is stable. Stability in sorting algorithms just means that items with identical keys will maintain their same order *relative to each other*.

So in your last example you have:

```
(4,1)(4,0)(1,0)
```

And the insertion sort results in:

```
(1,0)(4,1)(4,0)
```

The items `(4,1)` and `(4,0)` have maintained their same order relative to each other. That is, `(4,1)` came before `(4,0)` in the original array, and it's before that item in the final array. The sort is stable.

Also, the results of sorting any particular array with selection sort might indicate that selection sort is stable. That is, there's no guarantee that selection sort will change the relative order of equal items. For example, starting with:

```
(4,1)(1,0)(4,0)
```

Selection sort will produce

```
(1,0)(4,1)(4,0)
```

In that case, the selection sort did not change the relative order of `(4,1)` and `(4,0)`. But that doesn't mean that selection sort is stable. After all, even a stopped clock is right twice a day.